# Error con Arreglo al pasarlo de Desarrollo a Producción en Angular9

Tags: array, angular, typescript, angular9

Tengo una app desarrollada en Angular9. Esta funciona perfectamente en desarrollo pero al realizarle el ng build --prod --aot --base-href me comvierte mi arreglo a listar a un arreglo plano.
El arreglo inicial tipos de objetos que una vez llevado a prod se pierden.
[image: arreglo en desarrollo]

Este es mi arreglo en desarrollo mostrado en un console.log
ahora pongo como me lo devuelve en producción.
[image: arreglo en producción]

Comment: Puedes compartir to componente ts y html?

Comment: Sinceramente, yo veo la misma estructura en ambos arrays. Muestra tu código a ver si encontramos algo raro

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] No es la misma estructura, si notan son dos modelos diferentes.
En uno el municipio, la provincia y el rol son objetos en la otra solo números.
Ya lo solucione gracias a todos.
Al parecer el servidor donde esta desplegada la api se había colgado y los cambio de la actualización no se había ejecutado y por eso en pc local me devolvía una arreglo y el api otro.
Llevo todo el día en esto. Un día perdido por una sencillez.
c'est la vie...